# Could I find boxes(rows/columns) from lines?

Tags: c#, algorithm, autocad, dwg

There is a BOM table in the DWG. It is consist of lines and texts.
I want to make a Table obejct by this lines and texts.

I know that only lines attributes(start, end position), text position which are part of table.

However, I would like to know how many rows, column in table by using line's information.

Also, I should make table object that text are saved.

I tried to exact just text information (position) to make a table object. but it was problem to sort by order.

[image: Table1]
[image: Table2]
[image: Table3]

Comment: Can't you just count horizontal and vertical lines? Can you show some example data?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Wait a minute please.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Could you check the table 1,2,3 images?

Comment: Ok, so the data is very clean and you can indeed simply count vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yeah. I did. Anyway. Thanks for your intention. Haha